Browsers' API implementaion
When we run JavaScript in browsers and call built in API (e.g. DOMParser.parseFromString or Range.createContextualFragment) do we call precompiled C++ code or browsers have these methods written in JS ?
I can find C++ implementaion in source code
https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev/blob/master/dom/base/DOMParser.cpp

But is this linked to JS?

For some, C++, for others, JS. Maybe even some C, Rust, assembler language. An API is - as the name says - an interface, where it doesn't matter to the caller how it is implemented.
